# Maven hibernate dependecy without version. Spring petclinic

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, version, pom.xml

Studying spring-project example, i have found a code fragment:

```
        <!-- HIBERNATE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

It works fine there, but when I tried to add the same fragment into my pom.xlm, I got `[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar is missing.`

Give me explanation, why it works here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/pom.xml, but doesn't work in generic pom.xml.

Comment: Did you add the bom (bill-of-materials) from the example as well?

Comment: @wjans I didn't add the bom, and now i figured out that here was my mistake.You gave the answer first, so i can accept your answer as right, if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to include the bom in your `<dependencyManagement>` section as well.  This bom includes the version for all dependencies.

See [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) for more information on bom's.

Answer (score 1):

This is becasue it uses `<dependencyMangement>` to import `platform-bom` which is essentially a POM artifact which defines the default dependencies.

Maven using it to resolve the Hibernate dependency's version (Maven must know the 3 GAV properties to identify the artifact).